# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:unknown error:cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222 from unknownerror:unable to discover open pages

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I managed to connect selenium driver to an already opened chrome session with the following method in python

```
def iniciar_google_previa():
   os.system('google-chrome --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/home/natanael/.config/google-chrome/Default" &')
   time.sleep(2)
   options1 = Options()
   options1.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
   chrome_driver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options1)
   
   return driver
```

And it worked really good, then I can open any site with `driver.get("site_url")` to start scraping.

I wanted to try the same with docker containers. Installed all the requierements for the dockerfile, built it and then tried to run it but I get the following error

```
  File "final1.py", line 104, in <module>
   iniciar_ciclo()
 File "final1.py", line 21, in iniciar_ciclo
   driver = iniciar_google_previa()
 File "final1.py", line 67, in iniciar_google_previa
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options1)
 File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
   desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
 File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
   self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
   response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
 File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222
from unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

I thought it was because it was trying to run a GUI so I added
`--headless`

`google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/home/natanael/.config/google-chrome/Default"`  
but got the same error.

already tried installing
`xvfb`

and then

`xvfb-run google-chrome --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/home/natanael/.config/google-chrome/Default"`

which gave the output

`DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/52bbc92b-e096-4897-8661-233ee573edaf`

apparentley it executes the chrome session but is still unable to connect to it and I don't know what else to try

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? I just run into this same situation, and totally have no idea

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. I solved it but don't remeber exactly how or whats the reason, but I will try it again and let you know if I find the solution, but it is possible.

Comment: @KaKa try running the following in your terminal "xhost si:localuser:root" that solved the X display connection for me. then run your container again and it should let you execute the GUI.

Comment: looks like it's my vpn program block my connection, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

I just encountered this very same problem on my Mac OS where I had created a program that runs via SSH from my iPhone. This means that I'm running my Python program from the terminal instead of my IDE. And since I'm also first getting another URL without the 9222 debugger port option something special happened:

> options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

This resulted in the terminal connecting to the session I was running. Therefore something like "Chrome Helper (Renderer) > main.py" pops up above the terminal. It will look like

[image: this]

but when running the command below you want it to look something like

[image: this].

This seems to have interrupted this command that I ran afterwards:

```
string = "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"
            kbd.write(string, 0.1)
            sleep(5)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
```

**Solution**

This solution that worked for me was opening a new terminal window, where I then put in the same command `"/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"`

Which opens a session with the designated port.

This was done by using os.system to spell out a command to open that window:

```
os.system('open -a Terminal -n')
            sleep(3)
```

After doing so, I opened a new session that was not connected to the other Chrome browser session, meaning that the title above the terminal had disappeared! Thus I also were able to open the new Chrome session with the designated port using the previously mentioned command without encountering the error in question!

Sample code:

```
            import os
            import pyautogui
            from time import sleep
            os.system('open -a Terminal -n')
            sleep(3)
            string = "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"
            kbd.write(string, 0.1)
            sleep(5)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            sleep(7)
```